# Unable to transfer file from Arista switch to external machine

Tags: python-3.x, scp

I am trying to transfer a file from Arista switch to an external machine using scp using pyeapi run_command.

Reference:
http://www.nycnetworkers.com/upgrade/copying-from-a-sftp-server/

Code:

```
import pyeapi
node = pyeayi.connect(transport='https', host='x.x.x.x', username='yyy', password='zzz', enable_pwd='xxx', return_node=True)
node.run_command(['copy flash:/file.log.gz scp://user:password@hostname/location/'], encoding='json')
```

But it throws the following error,

```
pyeapi.eapilib.CommandError: Error [1000]: CLI command 2 of 2 'copy flash:/file.log.gz scp:user:password@hostname/location/' failed: could not run command 
[Error copying flash:/file.log.gz to scp:user:password@hostname/location/ (Warning: Permanently added 'hostname' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). lost connection)]
```

Comment: Try running the scp command interactively. What happens?

Comment: @Kenster, Yes from the cli, running scp interactively works.